# Listview align currency on decimal poit

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.net I have a listview that has a column called "Amount". Negative numbers are displayed as (111.111) and porsitive #s are sdisplayed as 111.11. How can I right-align the numbers on decimal? If there wasn't any parenthesis it would be easy. However, this is a requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that simply right-aligning the column isn't good enough? You need to pad the `111.11` value to where the numbers line up perfectly with the `(111.111)` value?

Comment: here is a stack post that addresses this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332912/c-sharp-double-formatting-align-on-decimal-sign

Comment: Yes. I am trying to align (111.11) with 111.11 on the decimal. Not sure how I would do this in a Listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color the parenthesis the same as the background when the number is non-negative. Right align.

```
   <asp:ListView ID="MainListView" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table style="text-align:right;">
                <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span runat="server" style='<%# GetStyle() %>'>(</span>
                    <%# Eval("Item") %>
                    <span runat="server" style='<%# GetStyle() %>'>)</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var values = new[] { 
            new { Item = 123.12},
            new { Item = -133.34}
        };

        MainListView.DataSource = values;
        MainListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected string GetStyle()
    {
        if ((double)Eval("Item") < 0)
            return string.Empty;
        else
            return "color: white;";
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to return a different value in the code-behind "Getstyle()" depending on the browser(e.g. IE, chorme, Firefox, etc)

Comment: You could possibly use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be tricky.

There are two ways I can think of off hand to solve this problem.

1. Split the value up into two columns.  Right align the first column which contains anything before the decimal.  Left align the second column which contains the decimal and any trailing digits.  The downside to this is that it is in two different cells, which means you can't simply double click the content to copy & paste it, etc.
2. Use `Graphics.MeasureString` to calculate exactly how many pixels of padding you need to put on the column.

Comment: How would I determine if the listview item is a positive number so I can add padding? Is there an If statement I can use during itembound?

Comment: Yes, you can check during the `ItemDataBound` event of the `ListView`.  Check out this post for further explanation: [Get Data Value From ListView ItemDataBound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588500/get-data-value-from-listview-itemdatabound)