# access values of listview on code behind

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am creating a listview and binding data from database.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstService" DataTextField="Name"
    DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="True">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="table1">
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server">

                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server"
                    Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' Width="500px" Height="30px" />

                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="srvButton" runat="server"
                    Text="Add" OnClick="srvButton_Click" />
                <div class="voffset3"></div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

On code behind I am binding data on this field. I am fetching ID, Name column.

Now it is showing label and button with text "Add" on the button. But when I click on Add , I want to pass the value of "Id" associated with that list view item, how can I do that ?

```
protected void srvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the CommandArgument to your Button with the value of the item Id:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="srvButton" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="srvButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")' />
```

Now you can access it in the srvButton_Click handler:

```
protected void srvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button myButton = (Button)sender;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.CommandArgument.ToString());
    //----
}
```

Comment: thanks , is there a way I can bind the Text="Add" or "Remove" on the backend, I dont want assign Add as text by default.

Comment: Of course. You'll want to add an ItemDataBound handler to your ListView and in the handler you can assign the Text property to the Items based on your requirements. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588500/get-data-value-from-listview-itemdatabound

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `OnClick` to an `OnCommand` and send a `CommandArgument` along with it.

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="srvButton" runat="server"
    Text="Add" OnCommand="srvButton_Command" CommandArgument=<%# Eval("ID") %> />
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void srvButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Or you can use `OnItemCommand` event of the ListView along with the `DataKeyNames` property and use a button without an event bound to it.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstService" DataKeyNames="id"
    OnItemCommand="lstService_ItemCommand">

    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="srvButton" runat="server" Text="Add" />
```

And then in code behind get the datakey from the ListView.

```
protected void lstService_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(lstService.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex].Values[0]);
}
```